# How I can Block all China to entry to my server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, iptables, firewall, centos6

How I can Block **China** to entry to my server ? All China country ?
**By ipset and iptables**
I want by this to avoid DDOS attacks

OS: CentOS 6.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to mitigate DDOS attacks, then you need to have your ISP block the bad actors at their level.  Once the DDOS traffic has hit your router/firewall/server, it's already eating up your bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GeoIP service to obtain the list of known China IP, and then forbid their connection with iptables.

Have a look here [GeoLite2 Free Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) and download the CSV file. From the file `GeoLite2-Country-Locations-en.csv` you can find that China has a geoname id of 1814991. You then use that value to filter `GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv`

```
grep '1814991' GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv |
while read NETWORK STUFF
do
    # iptables code here
done
```

As suggested, asking the ISP is a much better idea.

Answer (score -1):

Well, get the IP range of all public IPs in China, add them to iptables with DROP.

Stupid idea though, you should be using some DDOS-avoiding options (for apache for example: [mod_evasive](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache-tips-and-tricks/modevasive-on-apache) or [mod_security](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu)) or even plain old limits in iptables like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
```